# Php random Variable to another Php page with SESSION

Tags: php

I create a PHP random number on page1.php , then i want send it to page2.php with SESSION ! . i sent it to page2.php but random variable changed on page2.php each time with refresh page !why!? , it variable must change with refresh page1 , not refresh page 2

page1.php

```
session_start();
$code = rand(11111,99999); $_SESSION['cod'] = $code; echo $code;
```

page2.php

```
session_start();
$code = $_SESSION['cod'] ;
```

Comment: _“but random variable changed on page2.php each time with refresh page”_ - how would you even know whether it changed, when you are not even making any output in _that_ script?

Answer (score -1):

You need to start the session with the same ID, to retrieve your session in another page. Check it out: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-id.php

You could have the following:
Page1:

```
<?php
session_id('my-session');
session_start(); 
$code = rand(11111,99999); 
$_SESSION['cod'] = $code; 
echo $code;
```

Page2:

```
<?php
session_id('my-session');
session_start(); 
$code = $_SESSION['cod'];
echo $code;
```

When you do `session_start()` with a `session_id()` defined, you'll retrieve the session from server.

Comment: Very thanks , but Unfortunately, the amount changes again on page2 :(

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same value inside `session_id()` method? They should be exactly the same in both pages.

Comment: yes jonathan , i just copy your codes on top of page1 and page2 .session ids on each pages are my-session

Comment: @FerFeri, try to use only the code i pasted here in your files.

Comment: This answer makes little sense, you do _not_ normally actively set the session id yourself from within your code. PHP by default takes it from the cookie that the session id was stored in with the response to the previous request.